# Display Currency in two decimals, but keeping all available decimals

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, string-formatting

Quick(I hope) question.
I've got this DataGrid, containing a few currency column's. What I can't seem to find is how to display the currency in 2 decimals. But maintaining a possible 3 or 4 decimal value in the cell. If tried some string-formatting but that actually changes the value. And so does a IValueConverter of course. So what am I missing? or could anybody point me in the right direction?

EDIT:
after the suggestion I tried something like this.

```
 <Style x:Key="DecimalTextBlockStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="{Binding StringFormat={}{0:C}}"/>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue"/>
    </Style>
```

and apply'd here:

```
if(e.PropertyType.FullName.Contains("Decimal"))
        {
            var cl = e.Column as DataGridTextColumn;
            if (cl != null)
            {
                //cl.Binding.StringFormat = "C2";
                Style Stl = (Style)FindResource("DecimalTextBlockStyle");
                cl.CellStyle = Stl;

            }}
```

But what I Dont Get is WHY! are the value's in those columns nice and red text, blue background.. but unformated string, just shows 0,000 in stead of €0,00

Comment: did you also try to use the data annotation DisplayFormat? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `StringFormat` or a one-way `Converter` should not change the actual value. Both of those are only used for display purposes.

For example, this will show the decimal value in currency format with 2 decimal places, but it will not trim `SomeDecimal` to two-decimal places

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeDecimal, StringFormat=C2}" />
```

Perhaps you are looking to display a value using 2 digits, but edit it using the full 4 digits. If this is the case, I would suggest using a Style Trigger to show the unformatted value while it's being edited.

```
<Style x:Key="DecimalTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding SomeDecimal, StringFormat=C2}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding SomeDecimal}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**Edit**

Per your request below to apply this style to a `DataGridCell`, you can either use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` and place a TextBox inside it with this style applied, or you can use the `ElementStyle` and `EditingElementStyle` properties to set the binding format

```
<DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding SomeDecimal, StringFormat=C2}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding SomeDecimal}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: sorry, been away for a few day's, building now. But looks like the perfect anwser. Just tryíng to adapt it a bit to accommodate my DataGrid, AutoGenerated columns andsofort..

Comment: On a textbox it works fine. But I cant seem to get it to work on a datagridcell.. which is autogenerated..

Comment: @Daanvl Try applying the style to the `DataGridBoundColumn.CellStyle`, and set the `ContentStringFormat` property instead of the `Text` property.

Comment: like this? <Setter Property="ContentStringFormat" Value="C2"/> or <Setter Property="ContentStringFormat" Value="{}{0:C}"/> this or
<Setter Property="ContentStringFormat" Value="{Binding StringFormat=C2}"/> cus none work.. I appreciate your effort btw! I now you are right... but I'll keep fiddling with the properties

Comment: @Daanvl I thought the first syntax would work, but since it doesn't you'll probably have to use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` instead of a `DataGridTextColumn`, and apply the style directly to the `TextBox`.

Comment: Oke, I will look in to that. But what is the reason that the backcolor of the datagridcell and the forecolor of the text inside the textblock/box is affected by the style and not the stringformat? I'm going to look at some output dumps i think..

Comment: @Daanvl I'm thinking its some kind of bug, because it shouldn't be behaving like that.

Comment: @Daanvl I've edited my answer to include an alternative way of formatting the string using the element styles. Note that there is no `Binding="{Binding SomeValue}"` on the actual `DataGridTextColumn` itself

Comment: I'll give it a shot. but me employer want's me to move on.. hope I'll post a result by Friday though...

Answer (score -1):

My first instinct is to just have a string with two decimals and use whatever structure you use to populate the datagrid if you need the full precision.

If you really need both values accessible from the DataGrid, I'd create two columns, one that's a decimal and has full precision, and another that's a string with two decimals.  You can show/hide the columns as needed so that the appropriate version is displayed at the appropriate time.

Comment: seems like kind of a hack... and not positive for performance in a grid that has 70+ columns and 10+ of those are currency..