# WPF VB.net How to format column in datagrid to show decimal number?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I don't know how to convert column in datagrid in WPF to show 2 decimal places.
Can somebody help me?

This is my code for filling datagrid.

```
Public Sub ListaZaposlenikaZaObracun()
    databasePath = lblPath.Content
    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" &
    " Data Source=" & databasePath & ";Persist Security Info=False;")
    cn.Open()
    cm = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT *  From PripremaObracuna", cn)
    adp = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cm)
    adp.Fill(ds, "PripremaObracuna")
    DgvPriprema.ItemsSource = ds.Tables("PripremaObracuna").AsDataView()
End Sub
```

Above code work , now i need code for converting 6 column to show 2 decimal places.

XML code is :

```
<Window x:Class="Obracun"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PlateApp"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Obracun" Height="666.848" Width="1250.529" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Closing="Window_Closing">
<Grid>

    <TextBox x:Name="TxtMjesec" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="347,70,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Mjesec" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="TxtFirstDay" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="40,114,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Period od" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="118"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="TxtLastDay" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="188,114,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Period do" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="113"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="CmbMjesec" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="40,73,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="118"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="CmbGodina" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="183,73,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="118" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.042,0"/>
    <Label Content="Mjesec" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="40,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="112"/>
    <Label Content="Godina" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="183,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="118"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="DgvPriprema" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="337" Margin="10,172,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1223" MinWidth="100" MinHeight="28" ColumnHeaderHeight="50" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">


    </DataGrid>
    <Button x:Name="BtnPopuna" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="38" Margin="532,68,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="147"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblPath" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="10,602,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="111"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblAktiv" Content="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="29" Margin="449,127,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="112"/>
    <Button x:Name="BtnObracunaj" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="763,65,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="136" Height="44"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtIznosOdbitka" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="587,129,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That code isn't related to WPF, data binding or formatting. What does the XAML look like? The binding expressions? You can specify a format string in multiple locations, eg using the `StringFormat` property in the binding expression of a `DataGridTextColumn` or `DataGridBoundColumn`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display Currency in two decimals, but keeping all available decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637032/display-currency-in-two-decimals-but-keeping-all-available-decimals)

Comment: I added my XML code to the question.

Comment: You haven't added *any* columns to the grid. Add the columns and specify the format in the `StringFormat` property of the binding expression

Comment: Your connection is never closed. Although a `DataAdapter .Fill()` method will open and close a connection for you, if it finds an open connection it will leave it open.

Comment: Mary I know that! On form close i closed connection cn.Close(). You see just one litlle part of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution!
After binding and using StringFormat property, I added desired format.

Example of format:
StringFormat={}{0:N}

To show number seperated with comma (1,00), I added ConverterCulture=hr-HR

Example:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=OsnovicaPOreza,StringFormat={}{0:N}, ConverterCulture=hr-HR}" Header="Osnovica poreza" >
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Right" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
```

**Thanks to all!**